# How do I specify the include directory for an imported shared library using CMake?

Tags: cmake

I am using cmake version 3.9.1.

I have a third party shared library and header file in my source tree. I am trying to add it as a link target.

All the documentation I can find says that this should work:

`test.cpp`

```
#include "ftd2xx.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FT_HANDLE handle;
    FT_STATUS status = FT_Open(1, &handle);

    return 0;
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.6)
project(test_proj CXX)
add_subdirectory(ftdi)
add_executable(mytest test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mytest ftd2xx)
```

`ftdi/CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_library(ftd2xx SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(ftd2xx PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set_target_properties(ftd2xx PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

However compiling test.cpp, which includes "ftd2xx.h", complains that it cannot find the header file and the relevant `-I<path>` entry is missing from the generated makefiles.

If I specify the library as `INTERFACE` rather than `SHARED IMPORTED` then the header file is found correctly, but CMake barfs on setting the `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property.

If I specify the library as `INTERFACE` rather than `SHARED IMPORTED` and then use `target_link_libraries` to point directly to the library file than this works for Windows but not for Linux.

I'd appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CMake documentation does actually answer this one, but so concisely, and in the middle of a much larger paragraph, that it is easy to miss:

```
The target name has scope in the directory in which it is created and below, but the GLOBAL option extends visibility.
```

I am using the target name in a higher level directory, so I need to declare the library as `SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL` rather than just `SHARED IMPORTED`.

Final code is:

```
add_library(ftd2xx SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(ftd2xx PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

And then for Windows:

```
    set_target_properties(ftd2xx PROPERTIES IMPORTED_IMPLIB ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/win32/ftd2xx.lib)
    set_target_properties(ftd2xx PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/win32/ftd2xx.dll)
```

And for Linux:

```
    set_target_properties(ftd2xx PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/i386/libftd2xx.so)
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this in a cross-platform way ? In our team, we're working on both Linux and Windows and I'd really like something portable, isn't there something like that in cmake ? I've been looking but haven't found...

Comment: We keep our Windows libraries separate from our Linux ones, hence why we have separate lines for each platform. Plus the filenames are different and Windows has import libraries and Linux doesn't. However just wrap each section in the appropriate platform detection CMake code like `if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Windows")` and `if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL "x86_64")`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did but I find it a pity that everything in the export/import mechanic is OS/CPU/config-agnostic except this. :-(